# How to align sliced images in html?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I was given some sliced images to put together in an html. I did not slice them myself. I built a table. For each row, I placed 4 images with borders that need to be aligned. The final html should look like a grid with the borders of all the images aligned correctly. However, I noticed that in a specific row, the 4 original images do have the same dimensions. Eg.

I've tried changing the width and the height of all the images,  no margin/padding in the table and the cells. But, the borders are not aligned horizontally and vercally. Here's an example of one of the rows with original dimensions of the images. I know that some of the rules might be redundant but I was just trying everything without finding a solution.

Thank you for your quick feedback.

```
<html>        
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>No name</title><style type="text/css">
img {vertical-align: top; margin:0 auto 0 auto; padding:0}
table, td {border:0; padding:0; margin:0; border-collapse: collapse; cellpadding:0; cellspacing:0;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<pre width="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tr>
<td id="imgA"><a href=""><img src="ImageA" width="187" height="127" alt=""/></a></td>
<td id="imgB"><a href=""><img src="ImageB" width="184" height="127" alt=""/></a></td>
<td id="imgC"><a href=""><img src="ImageC" width="182" height="126" alt=""/></a></td>
<td id="imgD"><a href=""><img src="ImageD" width="187" height="126" alt=""/></a></td>
</tr>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lol dude nobody does this anymore

Comment: I'd recommend using divs and css instead of tables, not only is it less troublesome it's much faster. This method was outdated back when Henry VIII was running the show :P

Comment: My advice would be to paste the pictures back together using a graphics program. But anyway, if you're going to use HTML, please use correct HTML. Your browser will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

table, td  img
{
width :100%;
height:100%
}

Apply border in img class